# How to bind a void array using pybind11

Tags: pybind11

I have a structure as follows

```
struct _name{
  void* person[3];
}name;
```

I tried to copy elements into a python array but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to use the bound result? There is no such thing a a `void*` in Python, unless perhaps if you want to work with capsules, so the easiest to work with is a properly sized integer type, which can subsequently be handed to ctypes, rebound, etc.

In cppyy, I do the exactly that. Example:

```
import cppyy

cppyy.cppdef("""
typedef struct _name{
  void* person[3];
} name;
""")

n = cppyy.gbl.name()
print(n.person[0])
```

which prints whatever the first pointer points to (it's uninitialized in this example) as an integer address, and `cppyy.bind_object()` allows rebinding of the pointer to a proxy.

To do the same in pybind11, you can for example do:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/pytypes.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>

typedef struct _name {
  void* person[3];
} name;

PYBIND11_MODULE(name, m)
{
    pybind11::class_<name>(m, "name", pybind11::buffer_protocol())
        .def(pybind11::init<>())
        .def_property("person", [](name &n) -> pybind11::array {
            auto dtype = pybind11::dtype(pybind11::format_descriptor<uintptr_t>::format());
            auto base = pybind11::array(dtype, {3}, {sizeof(uintptr_t)});
            return pybind11::array(
                dtype, {3}, {sizeof(uintptr_t)}, n.person, base);
        }, [](name& n) {});
}
```

which gives you a numpy array of the proper integer type and length. Example use:

```
>>> import name
>>> n = name.name()
>>> n.person
array([0, 0, 0], dtype=uint64)
>>>
```

where again the values happen to be what they are, as they're uninitialized w/o a constructor for the `struct _name`.